# Terraform Error: KMS Key policy MalformedPolicyDocumentException: The new key policy will not allow you to update the key policy in the future

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-kms

I keep getting this error but I can't seem to spot what is wrong with my policy. Can someone help? This is my aws_kms_key_policy?

```
resource "aws_kms_key_policy" "kms_key" {
  key_id = aws_kms_key.kms_key.key_id
    
  policy = jsonencode({
    Id      = "kms-key-policy",
    Statement = [
       {
         Effect = "Allow",
         Principal = {
           Service = "states.amazonaws.com"
         },
         Action = [
           "kms:Encrypt",
           "kms:Decrypt",
           "kms:ReEncrypt",
           "kms:GenerateDataKey",
           "kms:DescribeKey",
           "kms:PutKeyPolicy",
           "kms:CreateGrant"
         ],
         Resource = aws_kms_key.kms_key.arn
       }
     ]
  })
}
```

I can't seem to spot what is incorrect with my policy.

**Update**

I've now added the root account to my policy:

```
resource "aws_kms_key_policy" "kms_key" {
  key_id = aws_kms_key.kms_key.key_id

  policy = jsonencode({
    Id = "kms-key-policy",
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid    = "Allow administration of the key",
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          "AWS" = "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:root"
        },
        Action = [
          "kms:Create*",
          "kms:Describe*",
          "kms:Enable*",
          "kms:List*",
          "kms:Put*",
          "kms:Update*",
          "kms:Revoke*",
          "kms:Disable*",
          "kms:Get*",
          "kms:Delete*",
          "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
          "kms:CancelKeyDeletion",
        ],
        Resource = "*"
      },
      {
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          Service = "states.amazonaws.com"
        },
        Action = [
          "kms:Encrypt",
          "kms:Decrypt",
          "kms:ReEncrypt",
          "kms:GenerateDataKey",
          "kms:DescribeKey",
          "kms:CreateGrant"
        ],
        Resource = aws_kms_key.kms_key.arn,
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

It first applied fine but now I'm getting the following error if I try to redeploy the same code even though no changes have been made:

```
│ Error: attaching KMS Key policy (7f01f1d8-2b2f-4d23-97df-34e65401dfa8): updating policy: waiting for completion: timeout while waiting for state to become 'TRUE' (last state: 'FALSE', timeout: 10m0s)
```

When I first applied it after adding the root account user it was applied successfully. Is there a reason why this I'm getting this error?

Comment: You don't need the entire ARN in "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:root", the account number is more than enough. It is also a good idea to declare a local variable with your account number to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you also want to allow the policy to be updated by a user from your AWS account. Right now there is no way to update the policy as you are only allowing AWS service to perform some actions. To fix this, I would add something like:

```
resource "aws_kms_key_policy" "kms_key" {
  key_id = aws_kms_key.kms_key.key_id

  policy = jsonencode({
    Id      = "kms-key-policy",
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid = "Allow administration of the key",
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          "AWS" = "arn:aws:iam::<your AWS account ID>:user/<user name>"
        },
        Action = [
          "kms:Create*",
          "kms:Describe*",
          "kms:Enable*",
          "kms:List*",
          "kms:Put*",
          "kms:Update*",
          "kms:Revoke*",
          "kms:Disable*",
          "kms:Get*",
          "kms:Delete*",
          "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
          "kms:CancelKeyDeletion"
         ],
         Resource = "*"
      },
      {
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          Service = "states.amazonaws.com"
        },
        Action = [
          "kms:Encrypt",
          "kms:Decrypt",
          "kms:ReEncrypt",
          "kms:GenerateDataKey",
          "kms:DescribeKey",
          "kms:CreateGrant"
        ],
        Resource = aws_kms_key.kms_key.arn
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

This will allow only the user that you specify to administer the KMS key. If you want to allow the account root user to administer the key, you can use the following:

```
Principal = {
  "AWS" = "arn:aws:iam::<your AWS account ID>:root"
}
```

As per the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_version.html), the `"Version"` element is required:

> `2012-10-17`. This is the current version of the policy language, and you should always include a `Version` element and set it to `2012-10-17`.

If you have a different identity that needs to administer the key, you can see more examples in the [re:Post article](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/update-key-policy-future).

Comment: Thanks Marko. I've added the relevent role to administer the key but I keep getting the same error. I'm using a pipeline to deploy my code which assumes role in to the AWS account. My role for the pipeline has the exact the same permissions as it does within this policy.

Comment: Can you explain what you did? In other words, what ARN did you add? Also, in that case, using the account root user might not be a bad idea.

Comment: I used the ARN of my IAM Role that is used for my pipeline.

Comment: Can you then update the question with the changes you made?

Comment: Updated Marko. I'm now getting separate issue where Terraform is timing out when changing the policy. Have you hit this error before?

Comment: I meant update the question with what has changed, not my answer. :)

Comment: Sorry. Updated the question now. If you can see that I'm now getting a separate error

Comment: It seems you didn't copy the entire answer, you are missing this: `Version = "2012-10-17",` in your policy.

Comment: Would that fix the timing out error that I’m getting?

Comment: Well, have you tried adding it?

Comment: Yes it worked. You need to add in version otherwise the policy will never be able to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

This statement only allows the principal `states.amazonaws.com` to ever do anything with the key ever again. It blocks you, the owner of the key, from ever modifying the key in the future. That's why it is rejecting the policy.